# Unix command sed replace in a variable

Tags: shell-script, sed, command

I want to remove brackets [] and quotes around each value and add quotes at start and end.

X= ['8922','9292','3220']

I want output as below.

Y = '8922,9292,3220'

How can I do this. Please suggest.

Comment: On stack exchange sites it's strongly encouraged to share what approach you
have tried so far (preferably in the form of some code, if applicable). Many
users don't want to spend their time simply doing people's coding tasks for
them, but all users are happy to _help_ you solve a problem!

Answer (score 1):

As simple as this: Replace the opening bracket and a quote with a single quote, replace the comma between the quotes with just a comma and a quote along the closing bracket with a single quote again:

```
sed "s/\['/'/;s/','/,/g;s/']/'/" file
```

The trick is usually to find what makes a pattern unique.

Comment: Wow!  You posted that in under eight minutes.  So you fulfilled the projection of six to eight minutes!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a shell variable `X` with a value set like so:

```bsh
X="['8922','9292','3220']"
```

You may then remove the single quotes and the square brackets using `tr`.  You may insert new single quotes at the same time too:

```bsh
Y="'$( printf '%s' "$X" | tr -d "[]'" )'"
```

If you're using `bash` or `zsh`, you could do that in a slightly more compact way:

```bsh
Y="'${X//[][\']/}'"
```